# Grouped UITableView have small extra space on bottom on iOS 15+

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios15

Grouped UITableview has an extra small space on the bottom on iOS 15+

this functions doesn't help

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    .leastNonzeroMagnitude
}

tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = .leastNonzeroMagnitude
```

[image: example]

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: I checked, extra spacing at bottom = 20

Comment: change the background color to table tableView.backgroundColor = .white

Comment: That is the default design of a Grouped table view. You can try this to change it: `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -20, right: 0)`

Comment: The solution was to migrate to UICollectionView

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        .leastNormalMagnitude
    }
```

Comment: This methods doesn't work. Please read the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had this 20pt padding at the bottom of each section with `tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)` returning `.leastNormalMagnitude`, too. But when I returned `nil` from `tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:)`, it worked and the bottom padding disappeared